# How to read JSON file that contains list of dictionaries into pandas data frame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got a list of dictionaries in a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[{"url": "http://www.URL1.com", "date": "2001-01-01"}, 
 {"url": "http://www.URL2.com", "date": "2001-01-02"}, ...]
```

but I'm struggling to import it into a pandas data frame — this should be pretty easy, but I'm blanking on it. Anyone able to set me straight here?

Likewise, what's the best way to simply read it into a list of dictionaries to use w/in python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd

lis = [{"url": "http://www.URL1.com", "date": "2001-01-01"}, 
       {"url": "http://www.URL2.com", "date": "2001-01-02"}]

print pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lis)

         date                  url
0  2001-01-01  http://www.URL1.com
1  2001-01-02  http://www.URL2.com
```

Or you can use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

lis = [{"url": "http://www.URL1.com", "date": "2001-01-01"}, {"url": "http://www.URL2.com", "date": "2001-01-02"}]

print pd.DataFrame(lis)

         date                  url
0  2001-01-01  http://www.URL1.com
1  2001-01-02  http://www.URL2.com
```

Answer (score 6):

While `from_dict` will work here, the prescribed way would be to use [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) with `orient='records'`.  This parses an input that is

> list-like `[{column -> value}, ... , {column -> value}]`

Example: say this is the text of `lis.json`:

```
[{"url": "http://www.URL1.com", "date": "2001-01-01"}, 
 {"url": "http://www.URL2.com", "date": "2001-01-02"}]
```

To pass the file path itself as input rather than a list as in @jezrael's answer:

```
print(pd.read_json('lis.json', orient='records'))
        date                  url
0 2001-01-01  http://www.URL1.com
1 2001-01-02  http://www.URL2.com
```